# How to get value of dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I want to get value of dataframe for add to MySQL. This is my dataframe.

```
l_id = df['ID'].str.replace('PDF-', '').item()
print(type(l_id))
```

It show error like this.

```
ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar
```

If I not use .item() It cannot add to MySQL. How to get value of dataframe ?

Comment: i think you want to use `.values` instead of `.item()`

Comment: @luigigi Please don’t use `.values` or recommend its use, the docs explicitly discourage doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `replace` with `nan` instead of `''` and remove nans and get actual item:

```
l_id = df['ID'].str.replace('PDF-', pd.np.nan).dropna().item()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no attribute .item() in dataframe, but you can do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['PDF-0A1','PDF-02B','PDF-03C'],columns=['ID']) #small dataframe to test

for ids in df.ID:

    l_id = ids.replace('PDF-','')   
    print(l_id)
    #0A1
    #02B
    #03C
```